# QML/Android Автоматическая панель SELECT/COPY/PAST сдвигает всё окно

Tags: android, qt, qml

QML/Android 8

В окне размещён многострочный редактор `TextArea` с возможностью выделать текст.

```
TextArea {
    selectByMouse: true
    clip: true
    font.pixelSize: 10
}
```

Если выделить часть текста, сверху появляется автоматическая панель SELECT/COPY/PAST действиями и сдвигает всё окно вниз. Что нужно сделать, чтобы панель с действиями SELECT/COPY/PAST появлялась поверх qml окна, чтобы компоненты, размещенные на окне не сдвигались?

Экспериментирую на пустом проекте Qt 5.10.2

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    TextArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            topMargin: parent.height / 8
        }
        height: parent.height / 4
        selectByMouse: true
        text: "TextArea..."
        font.pixelSize: 10
        clip: true
    }
}
```

TextArea размещён так, чтобы быть ниже всплывающей сверху панели (если она будет всплывать поверх окна).

Проделал уже много экспериментов. Описывать их особого смысла нет, так как пока всё мимо.

Answer (score 0):

Помогает такой код в mainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
```